# How to solve Error executing action `create` on resource 'file[myfile]'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, unix, devops, chef-infra

Getting below error while running chef in local

```
\[9:37 am, 24/02/2023\] +91 78387 70136: FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /Users/sonashar/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
\[2023-02-24T09:21:31+05:30\] FATAL: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\[2023-02-24T09:21:31+05:30\] FATAL: PLEASE PROVIDE THE CONTENTS OF THE stacktrace.out FILE (above) IF YOU FILE A BUG REPORT
\[2023-02-24T09:21:31+05:30\] FATAL: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\[2023-02-24T09:21:31+05:30\] FATAL: Errno::EROFS: file\[myfile\] (test-cookbook::test-recipe line 1) had an error: Errno::EROFS: Read-only file system @ rb_sysopen - myfile
\[9:37 am, 24/02/2023\] +91 78387 70136: Error executing action \`create\` on resource 'file\[myfile\]'
```

I want to create a resource?I am not able to do

Comment: Could you add the contents of `/Users/sonashar/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out` to your question?

Comment: The error is complaining about read-only filesystem. You'll have to check the path in which you are trying to create the file. Also, post the contents of the recipe that calls the `file` resource in question.